# How is it possible to override final writeObject() method in Custom Serialization (Java)

Tags: java, serialization, overriding, private, final

I'm learning about custom serialization and I don't understand how is it possible to overide the 2 methods writeObject() and readObject() because I know these 2 methods are final, and I know that final methods cannot be overriden.

writeObject() method from ObjectOutputStream:

```
public final void writeObject(Object obj) throws IOException
```

And writeObject() needs to be overriden like here:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream output) throws IOException
```

I understand that the new writeObject() method is private, but it is called using reflection by Java serialization mechanism. But I don't understand how is it possible to override a final method.

Account Class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Account implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 154754873L;
    String userName = "durga";
    transient String psw = "anushka";

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream output) throws IOException {

        output.defaultWriteObject();
        output.writeObject(psw);
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream input) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        input.defaultReadObject();
        psw = (String) input.readObject();
    }
}
```

SerializationDemo Class:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class SerializationDemo {

    public void serialize(Account a1, String fileName) {

        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName))) {

            oos.writeObject(a1); 

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

            System.out.printf("ERROR: %s", ex);

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            System.out.printf("ERROR: %s", ex);
        }
    }

    public Account deserialize(String fileName) {

        Account a2 = null;

        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("account.ser"))) {

            a2 = (Account) ois.readObject();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

            System.out.printf("ERROR: %s", ex);

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {

            System.out.printf("ERROR: %s", ex); 
        }

        return a2;
    }
}
```

SerializationApp Class:

```
public class SerializationApp {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Account a1 = new Account();

        System.out.println(a1.userName + " " + a1.psw);

        SerializationDemo demo = new SerializationDemo();

        demo.serialize(a1, "account.ser"); 

        Account a2 = demo.deserialize("account.ser");

        System.out.println(a2.userName + " " + a2.psw);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't override a final method, but you're not even trying to, since `writeObject(ObjectOutputStream output)` is an *overload*, not an override, of `writeObject(Object obj)`

Comment: Why do you want to override `writeObject` in `ObjectOutputStream`? Is providing `writeObject` and `readObject` methods in your class not enough? Why?

Comment: I know this is for learning, but you should steer away from Serializeable in the future. It's universally considered bad. There's better implementations in several libraries.

Comment: @killjoy It is certainly *not* 'universally considered bad'. It is the foundation of a large number of other things in Java. Don't make hasty generalizations.

Answer (score 1):

You are confused.

1. `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` is `final` and you cannot override it.
2. The `private void writeObject(ObjectOutput)` method you can use for custom serialization goes into your *own* `Serializable` class, not into a class that extends `ObjectOutputStream`. The question of overriding does not arise.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I think I understand this now, this is not overriding and the private method writeObject() is called by JVM using reflection.

Comment: Called by `ObjectOutputStream` using reflection, actually.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to override a `final` method.

But you don't need to.

One way to customize serialization is to provide `writeObject` and `readObject` methods (like you did):

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException;
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
```

Note that we don't talk about implementing or overriding methods here.

This should be actually enough - I wonder why you need to override `writeObject` in `ObjectOutputStream`.

If you want to customize serialization by subclassing the `ObjectOutputStream`, you still can "override" how objects are written. For this, subclass `ObjectOutputStream`, in the subclass call `super()` and override `writeObjectOverride`. If you call the protected `ObjectOutputStream()` constructor, the `enableOverride` flag is set to `true` and the final method `writeObject` (which you can't override) delegates to `writeObjectOverride` (which can be overridden).